# Is it possible to re-consolidate student loans after marriage?

Tags: united-states, student-loan, loan-consolidation

I consolidated my student loans down to two (for the Sub and Unsub halves) shortly after graduating college a few years ago.

My wife never consolidated her loans.

Is it possible to consolidate hers and mine into a single (or maybe two, for Sub & Unsub) loan?

If so, how?

If not, can I reconsolidate/refinance both of our loans to [possibly] lower interest rates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/facts_5195047_student-loan-consolidation-faq.html):

> Loans can only be re-consolidated if the borrower has a new loan to add.

ABC News [says](http://abcnews.go.com/Business/married-couples-student-loan-debt/story?id=11258995):

> In 2006, Congress eliminated joint consolidation loans for married couples

So it would seem that you can consolidate her loans into one or two loans, but those cannot be combined with yours.